# Using ReportLab with Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, reportlab

I am having some issues creating a geoprocessing service within arcmap using reportlabs pdf toolkit. The script runs fine outside of arcmap, however when i try and run it in arcmap to publish as a service I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Y:\Server\Reporting\test\test_report.py", line 19, in <module>
    createPDF(pdf_path, user_input)
  File "Y:\Server\Reporting\test\test_report.py", line 16, in createPDF
    c.save()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1215, in save
    self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 219, in SaveToFile
    data = self.GetPDFData(canvas)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 244, in GetPDFData
    return self.format()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 424, in format
    IOf = IO.format(self)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 869, in format
    fcontent = format(self.content, document, toplevel=1)   # yes this is at top level
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 80, in format
    f = element.format(document)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 1558, in format
    return PD.format(document)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 676, in format
    L = [(format(PDFName(k),document)+b" "+format(dict[k],document)) for k in keys]
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 80, in format
    f = element.format(document)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 607, in format
    s.decode('pdfdoc')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\rl_codecs.py", line 1047, in _rl_codecs
    if name.startswith(e): return RL_Codecs.__rl_codecs(e)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_RL_Codecs__rl_codecs'
```

My very simple test code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import arcpy

base_path = r"\\hc-gis\GIS_Data\Server\Reporting\test"

pdf_path = base_path +  r"\output\Report.pdf"
arcpy.AddMessage(pdf_path)

user_input = 'Welcome to Reportlab!'#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.AddMessage("Generating Report...")

def createPDF(path, input):
    c = canvas.Canvas(path)
    c.drawString(100,750,input)
    c.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createPDF(pdf_path, user_input)
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, pdf_path)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Complete')
```

My goal here is to return a PDF as a result of the user input.

Comment: Are you running this in ArcMap as a Python script tool or from its Python window?

Comment: Python script tool to be published as a gp service.

Comment: I encounter similar errors when using it as a Python script for gp service. Hope someone could answer it.

Comment: I am still unsure what caused this error, however I was able to publish the same GP service using another computer without any issues. ArcGIS 10.3 on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to ians's comments on Feb 25, I had the same issue whilst troubleshooting an unrelated issue in my script, and when re-running a python script I was debugging within ArcMap, I would start experiencing this problem after the other bug triggered in my code - however, this issue would then persist despite fixing the bug, until I restarted ArcMap and started the job from fresh, at which point my now fixed script would run fine.

It seems like ArcMap was tripping up after the other bug, and just couldn't recover properly to get through running the updated script.

Posting in case this helps anyone, as his post helped me.